# Alexa Multi-capability Skills - get device endpointId in the Alexa request

Tags: voice, alexa-slot, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm implementing a multi capability skill in Alexa to add further utterances to those already provided by the Smart home skills.

Account linking, discovery and some smart home skill pre-built commands are already in place.
Now I should implement some custom commands using custom skills, but I can't understand how I can refer to a specific device discovered during the discovery intent.

As with smart home skill requests, I would need to receive in the request the device endpointId that the user wants to control.
An example of custom utterance could be: `Alexa, ask myCustomSkill to control {deviceName}`.

I can't find anything related in the documentation, can anyone help me please?